# How doo I resolve getting a 500 error when calling $.post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My website has a drawing tool. This drawing tool help met create an image (.png) from the drawing. Has been working for years now, but recently changed the wordpress theme.

Now I can't figure out what's going wrong.

I have the following code which is doing a POST request to a file in my theme folder

```
var templateUrl = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/generatepress';
  var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg",'',1.0);
  var jsnDataJSON = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(canvas));
  $('input[name=json]').val(jsnDataJSON);
  strDataURI = strDataURI.substr(22, strDataURI.length);

  var ajax_urll= templateUrl+"/ajax.php";   
  
        $.post(ajax_urll,
        { 
            str: strDataURI
        },
        function(data){
            var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(obj.status!="ERROR"){
            jQuery("#drawing").html(obj.image);
            jQuery("#drawingsaveresult").html("Drawing has been successfully saved");
            jQuery("#drawingsaveresult").fadeOut(10000);
            jQuery("input[name='drawing']").val(obj.imagename);
            }else{
                jQuery("#drawingsaveresult").html("Else error in saving drawing");
                jQuery("#drawingsaveresult").fadeOut(10000);
                }
        });
```

So this code is calling ajax.php file (file in theme folder) which does the following

```
<?php
session_start();

// require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/example.nl/wp-load.php' ); localhost
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;

$data = base64_decode($_POST["str"]);

$urlUploadImages = "oefeningen/";

$nameImage = rand()."drawing.png";

$img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

imageAlphaBlending($img, true);

imageSaveAlpha($img, true);
$response=array();
if($img) {
    imagepng($img, $urlUploadImages.$nameImage, 0);
    imagedestroy($img);
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); 
    $response['image']="<img src='".get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/oefeningen/".$nameImage."' width=100 height=150>";
    $response['imagename']=$nameImage;
    $response['status']="success";
    
}
else {
    $response['status']="ERROR";
}


echo json_encode($response);
```

But for some reason it's not working anymore. In the console it's giving the following error back
POST https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/generatepress/ajax.php 500

I can't find a resolution. Can someone assist me with this?

Comment: A 500 error means somewhere in your server's error logs there's a full error message.

Comment: The only error I'm seeing in my log files: 
[Mon Jan 25 14:28:08.743263 2021] [php7:error] [pid 1238] [client 85.159.237.73:0] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare generate_set_customizer_helpers() (previously declared in /home/public/sites/www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/generatepress/inc/customizer.php:20) in /home/public/sites/www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/generatepress/inc/customizer.php on line 20, referer: https://example.nl/oefeningen/toevoegen/?v=2

But this doesn't help me much

Comment: Well, you've got `generate_set_customizer_helpers` declared twice, or the file is being included twice. That's your issue.

Comment: You should write the response that you get with 500 server error, trance your request using Network XHR request from browser and place the response here that you get. And if your display error settings are off, please turn them on or turn on error logs and check the logs.

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name. But it looks like actually you have simply included the same PHP file twice in your script, because both locations mentioned are identical. Looks for excess uses of `include` or `require`. To guard against this kind of problem, consider using `include_once` or `require_once` instead.

Comment: @ImranZahoor OP already posted the error log entry, above your comment.

Comment: The error message mentions the same line in the same file twice, so in all likelihood, that file gets included/required twice. Where/how, we can hardly tell you with the info we have so far.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It looks unrelated to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Whether it's directly related to the code in your question or not isn't particularly relevant - it's a fatal error so it's stopping your script from executing,and you need to fix it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php are likely to be useful links for you

Comment: Anyway what exactly don't you understand? You've somehow included the same script twice inside your main script.That has resulted in the same function being declared twice with the same name...and clearly a script cannot have two functions with the same name, the PHP interpreter can never resolve that.

Comment: Well everything is working, except for the drawing tool. These are theme files which I didn't alter. I'm reading your links and trying to fix the fatal error. Thanks for the quick answer, really appreciate it.

Comment: You wrote the code stopped working after you changed the theme; are you sure the path in `var templateUrl = 'https://example.nl/wp-content/themes/generatepress';` is still the correct one?

Comment: Yes it's correct

Comment: So I've checked the /home/public/sites/www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/generatepress/inc/customizer.php file and it's showing the following functionality 

add_action( 'customize_register', 'generate_set_customizer_helpers', 1 );
/**
 * Set up helpers early so they're always available.
 * Other modules might need access to them at some point.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */
function generate_set_customizer_helpers() {
 require_once trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'inc/customizer/customizer-helpers.php';
}

Comment: As you said there is a require_once function in there

Comment: Ill try and ask the theme developer for a solution.